# designed component does not update at runtime in C#

Tags: c#

I have designed a simple component like this:

```
public sealed partial class MySimpleComponent : Control
{
    public PictureBox picRed=new PictureBox();

    public MySimpleComponent()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Controls.Add(picRed);
        picRed.Image = global::InterLockingV1.Properties.Resources.RedLamp1;
        picRed.SizeMode=PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        picRed.Dock=DockStyle.Fill;
    }

    public MySimpleComponent(IContainer container)
    {
        container.Add(this);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

when i compile my code, i can see the component in toolbox and can drag it on the form, it works well at design time (I can see the redlamp image in  picturebox), but when i execute the program, no image apears on the picturebox,
i tried to change it at runtime, but nothing changed:

```
MySimpleComponent1.picRed.Image=Image.FromFile(@"MyImagePath");
```

whould you please help me to tackle the problem?

Comment: You have 2 constructors, if second one is called during run-time you will not have `picRed` added.

Comment: The code that adds `picRed` should probably be inside the `InitializeComponent` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the code in Form_Load event